# Android testing menu content

Tags: java, android, junit

I create menu just like tutorial says.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I want to write a JUnit test that checks if menu items strings are correct. However I don't know how can I do something like getMenu() from outside MainActivity class and then get menu items to strings or a list. Also I can't declare field 'menu'. Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have a `menu.xml` file in your menu folder?

Comment: I would test the Content of my menu with Toasts.

Comment: Yes, i'm using xml file. The case is I want to use unit test, not to test inside app.

Comment: Sorry I was writing my answer. I saw this one comment of yours now....

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your menu like this:
Your Java file must contain among others the following.

**1.**

```
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
```

...

**2.**

```
   //Create options menu using menu_options_menu XML file
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

   //Set action for item select in options menu
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

        YOUR_ACTIVITY.this.finish();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.item0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose Action 0!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.item1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose Action 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.item2) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose Action 2!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.item3) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose Action 3!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.item4) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose Action 4!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

Your `menu.xml` file in the Folder menu could look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<item
    android:id="@+id/item0"
    android:title="Action0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:title="Action1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:title="Action3"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:title="Action3"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item4"
    android:title="Action4"/>
</menu>
```

Please mark this answer as the answer to your question with regard to menu testing if you're satisfied with the result or comment in case you have further questions.

Good luck.